# Scheduled job failure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a schedule job to take backup for every 8 hours in SQL Server 2008. Till day before yesterday everything was working fine but all of sudden the job got failed with the error message below.

Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "FilePath\FileName.BAK:" 112(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3271)  BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step failed.

I tried searching in google bout didn't get the exact idea. Consider me a newbee in SQL Server 2008

Any suggestions will be higly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for this error is lack of space to perform the backup.

Other reasons are a corrupt database or hardware problems.

Suggest you run `DBCC CHECKDB` as soon as you can.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried below things but no luck : 1. Running the job from from management studio- got success 2. DBCC CHECKDB - got no error message. So the space or hardware problem possiblities are not there.

Comment: Any further help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got it resolved. The problem was with network traffic on the server. I changed the time and it woked like a charm :) :)